# Tasks distribution among pods

Tags: kubernetes, distributed-computing

Is there any way to distribute tasks among pods in kubernetes. I have bunch of files on HDFS and I want to distribute them among my application pods.

Feature like Helix partition distribution will also work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this [RabbitMQ work queue example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html).

Comment: Thanks Janos for the suggestion. I know about messaging systems and other mechanism like locking to achieve it in distributed manner. I want to know if kubernetes provides any such functionality to achieve it